# "Join" Arrays with values from left array to keys from right array

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have to arrays that i want to join together without iterating them.
Backgroundinfo:

$Arr1 is an array of all Groups that a User is in.
$Arr2 is an array of all Contentpages associated to the Groups as the array key.

My aim is to get an array with all contentpages that the user is allowed to see

```
$Arr1 = array("Group1","Group3","Group5");

$Arr2["Group1"] = array("Content1","Content2");
$Arr2["Group2"] = array("Content5");
$Arr2["Group3"] = array("Content3");
```

My Result should be an array with all "Content" Elements:

```
array("Content1","Content2","Content3");
```

Is there some trick with array_fill_keys or array_merge to avoid iterating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `array_flip` and `array_intersect_key`.

```
$intersect = array_intersect_key($Arr2, array_flip($Arr1))
```

Then you can flatten that into one array using `array_merge`.

```
$content = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $intersect);
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/430592

Comment: + I always preach PHP has an array function for every need. This is great proof of that.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Does somebody know how this will be on performance side - in comparision with a foreach loop?